# Python sorting 2D array by the first element (not unique)

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I have a very big 2D array where the second elements are not unique. Something like this:

```
list = [ ['text43','value43'], 
         ['text23','value23'], 
         ['text12','value12'],
         ['text43','different_val_43'],
         ['text12','another_value12'], 
         ['text04','value04'], 
         ['text43','anohter_value43'] ]
```

I would like to sort it by the first element but not in alphabetical order, just in the order of appearance of first element. Desired output:

```
list = [ ['text43','value43'],
         ['text43','different_val_43'],
         ['text43','anohter_value43'],
         ['text23','value23'],
         ['text12','value12'],
         ['text12','another_value12'],
         ['text04','value04'] ]
```

Comment: `sorted(list1, key=lambda x: -int(x[0][-2:]))` ?

Comment: Hello @Birbal, you'll need to add some code that you have already tried to make work. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do not use `list` as the variable name of a python list. @BearBrown 's answer looks right.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesLandau ...actually was just an example, I have not named it `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom [sorting function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) that would return the index at which the first element of a sublist is first found, e.g.:

```
lst = [['text43','value43'],
       ['text23','value23'],
       ['text12','value12'],
       ['text43','different_val_43'],
       ['text12','another_value12'],
       ['text04','value04'],
       ['text43','anohter_value43']]

d = {}
for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    if item[0] not in d:
        d[item[0]] = i

lst.sort(key=lambda item: d[item[0]])
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[['text43', 'value43'],
 ['text43', 'different_val_43'],
 ['text43', 'anohter_value43'],
 ['text23', 'value23'],
 ['text12', 'value12'],
 ['text12', 'another_value12'],
 ['text04', 'value04']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look if this helps. Using [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

```
lst = [ ['text43','value43'], 
         ['text23','value23'], 
         ['text12','value12'],
         ['text43','different_val_43'],
         ['text12','another_value12'], 
         ['text04','value04'], 
         ['text43','anohter_value43'] ]

sorted(lst, reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
[['text43', 'value43'],
 ['text43', 'different_val_43'],
 ['text43', 'anohter_value43'],
 ['text23', 'value23'],
 ['text12', 'value12'],
 ['text12', 'another_value12'],
 ['text04', 'value04']]
```